# Chai using TypeScript, PhpStorm error

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, phpstorm, webstorm, chai

I'm trying to use Chai with TypeScript but I'm getting the following error on the `it()` line:

> Argument type() => FinishedRequest is not assignable to parameter type this.

This is the test code:

```
import * as mocha from 'mocha';
import * as chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

import app from '../src/App';

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('baseRoute', () => {

  it('should be json', () => {
    return chai.request(app).get('/')
    .then(res => {
      expect(res.type).to.eql('application/json');
    });
  });
});
```

The code runs successfully but it show that error in PhpStorm.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me in 2017.1.2 - the only issue reported for this code is '*Unused import*' for Mocha (I have TypeScript service disabled)

[image]

what PHPStorm version do you use? Please try invalidating caches - does the problem persist?